# phpMyAdmin reports one extra query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a large file that contains a mysqldump of a database. I searched for all the semicolons I come up with 378. When I upload the file to phpMyAdmin it reports 379 queries when doing an import. (I know that phpMyAdmin might not be reliable, but I just want to make sure I don't have a problem with the output of mysqldump)

Is there a way to find out what it thinks the extra query is? The dump file is pretty large and I don't want to share the information.

**EDIT:**

I have posted the database schema at:
http://blastohosting.com/pos_database.sql

It would be great if it could be determined to as why there is an extra query being reported by phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you why, necessarily, but I can say that I got exactly the same results: 378 semicolons, "379 queries executed".

However, here's the weird thing: when I removed the last two lines in the script:

```
(blank)
-- Dump completed on 2014-02-17 17:52:43
```

...PMA said "**378** queries executed".  It's evidently counting that final comment as a "query" even though it's ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can assume it is a bug/feature in phpMyAdmin. I would have never thought to try that.

Answer (score 0):

A dump file doesn't necessarily contain one semicolon per statement.

- Any CREATE TRIGGER or CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE FUNCTION statements have literal semicolons within their bodies, so it is common practice to change the client's statement terminator to something besides semicolon, to resolve the ambiguity.

  So you could be counting semicolons that aren't statement terminators. Likewise, MySQL may recognize more SQL statements executed that didn't use semicolon.
- MySQL [builtin commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) such as DELIMITER, CHARSET, USE, SOURCE, etc. don't need a terminator at all, but they may have one without error. They shouldn't be reported as statements executed by the server, but they may throw off your count of semicolons.
- Do you have any semicolons inside string literals or SQL comments?

Comment: I am not using Triggers, procedures, or functions. phpMyAdmin is reporting MORE statements than there are semicolons...is it possible that a statement a query could NOT end in a semicolon? I do not have any semi-colons inside string literals.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'm just putting out speculation, because you can't share the file itself.

Comment: Karin, I have edited the question and shared the database schema